# has fallen, versus is fallen

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage

Which is the is the better/correct phrase to choose?

- "the king has fallen", like *the king has died*

or

- "the king is fallen", like *the king is dead*

Comment: I'd say "the king has fallen". The second might feel more natural about a place/kingdom. There is another: "fallen is the king".

Comment: They both mean the same; 'is fallen' is archaic or fake-old-fashioned (e.g. in awful fantasy novels or games).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey In the meantime, I've found *is fallen*, in an "alternative bible" in the phrase *Babylon is fallen*. So you might be right with "fake-old-fashioned"

Comment: @Vickel - it's in the King James Bible, which is hardly 'alternative': Book of Revelations, Chapter 18 verse 2:    _Babylon the great is fallen, is fallen, and is become the habitation of devils_   Other translations use 'has' or even _''Fallen! Fallen is Babylon the Great!' She has become a dwelling for demons and a haunt for every impure spirit_ (New International Version)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey are you OK if I edit your comment into my Question? I've also this [The king has fallen](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/49917812-the-king-has-fallen)

Comment: @Vickel - sure, if it helps.

Comment: @Vickel - the answer, which I thought I had sufficiently conveyed, is 'Use _has fallen_ for normal purposes and _is fallen_ for cod-Tolkien 'Now is my sword drawn from its holy scabbard' stuff.

Comment: Also, _fallen_ suggests 'killed in battle' rather than 'died of natural causes'.

Answer (score 2):

Forming the present perfect using the verb 'to be' (am/are/is) instead of 'have' (have/has) before certain past participles, e.g. come, gone, arisen, fallen, etc, is very archaic.